# Convert grouped by df to a dict with a list of dicts

Tags: python, pandas

I've the following df:

```
                  timestamp           min           max  count
0 2022-10-23 22:00:00+00:00  1.000000e+09  9.000000e+99      0
1 2022-10-23 22:00:00+00:00  1.000000e+08  1.000000e+09      2
2 2022-10-23 22:00:00+00:00  1.000000e+07  1.000000e+08     39
3 2022-10-23 22:00:00+00:00  1.000000e+06  1.000000e+07    162
4 2022-10-23 22:00:00+00:00  1.000000e+05  1.000000e+06    491
5 2022-10-23 22:00:00+00:00  1.000000e+04  1.000000e+05    960
6 2022-10-23 22:00:00+00:00  1.000000e+03  1.000000e+04    287
7 2022-10-23 22:00:00+00:00  1.000000e+02  1.000000e+03    244
8 2022-10-23 22:00:00+00:00  1.000000e+01  1.000000e+02    416
9 2022-10-23 22:00:00+00:00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+01      1
```

And I'm trying to group it by timestamp to create the following structure:

```
items = {
    '2022-10-23 22:00:00+00:00': 
        [ 
            {'min': 1.000000e+09, 'max': 9.000000e+99, 'count': 0},
            {}, 
            ...
        ] 
}
```

I think that there's a way to do it doing something similar to:

```
df.groupby('timestamp')[['max', 'min','count']].apply(lambda g: g.values.tolist()).to_dict()
```

But I don't know what to change in the lambda function in order to get the result I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension with [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
items = {k: g.to_dict('records') for k,g in
         df.set_index('timestamp').groupby('timestamp')}
```

output:

```
{'2022-10-23 22:00:00+00:00': [{'min': 1000000000.0, 'max': 9e+99, 'count': 0},
                               {'min': 100000000.0, 'max': 1000000000.0, 'count': 2},
                               {'min': 10000000.0, 'max': 100000000.0, 'count': 39},
                               {'min': 1000000.0, 'max': 10000000.0, 'count': 162},
                               {'min': 100000.0, 'max': 1000000.0, 'count': 491},
                               {'min': 10000.0, 'max': 100000.0, 'count': 960},
                               {'min': 1000.0, 'max': 10000.0, 'count': 287},
                               {'min': 100.0, 'max': 1000.0, 'count': 244},
                               {'min': 10.0, 'max': 100.0, 'count': 416},
                               {'min': 0.0, 'max': 10.0, 'count': 1}]
}
```